# RESTful Api or Socket.IO

Tags: android, mysql, node.js, rest, socket.io

Im writing a mobile application. It connects to the node.js server and getting some data. 
Which is the best way to retrieving data from nodejs server?

My project architecture:

mySQL DB <-> node.js (Server) <--(socket.io or restful)--> mobile clients

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need a bidirectional real-time connection between your server and your client (e.g. a chat bot or a stock ticker), then socket.io would be a good choice.

However if you just need to fetch some data from time to time on the client from the server (and / or push some data), then a RESTful architecture makes more sense.

For most use cases a RESTful architecture is probably better. If you elaborate a bit more about what kind of data you're sharing between the client and the server, there could be a more precise answer.

Comment: hi, my datas can be image, text or video. But at first datas are text. Mobile clients monitoring the database, when the new data add the db from someone. Node.js server push the new data to mobile clients. Later, mobile can add the data to db.

Comment: In your case I'd probably use a RESTful architecture and then use GCM (https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) to notify the client that new data is available. Then the clients fetch the updated data.

Comment: why socket.io is useless for this project?

Comment: It's not useless, it would work as well. However if you don't need to constantly push data to and from the client it is quite expensive in terms of battery life and data to have an always open connection. By using GCM your app will only use data when it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: i understood, last question can i use GCM for ios? sorry for my questions, im new on mobile :)

Comment: No, GCM is the push notification service from Google for Android. For iOS you would need to use Apple's push notification service. Documentation for that can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html